# Send data to mainactivity from separate intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intentservice

```
Intent goMain = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);

goMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
goMain.putExtras(extras);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(goMain);
```

What I'm trying to do is, sending data from a separate `IntentService` o one and only `MainActivity`. What happens and which i would not prefer it to happen is bringing a new activity instead of the current running one. And additionally, the current running activity does not show the data sent from the intentservice. When I try removing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` I get "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag" error. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is causing your problem. If you want to use the existing instance of the `Activity`, use this set of flags:

```
goMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will remove any other activities from the task stack that are on top of `MainActivity`.

Setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will ensure that the existing instance of `MainActivity` will be used and a new one won't be created.

`MainActivity.onNewIntent()` will be called with the `Intent` you use.